# vertical alignment between two lines

Tags: html, css, alignment

I am having problems getting some html to line up visually the way I want.

I got two lines of text followed by a link.  I want the link vertically centered between the two lines not with he second line.  Aside from using a table I am not sure how to do this and a table seems overkill to accomplish this.

So I started with this

```
<div class="(float right class)">
    Line 1<br />Line 2
    <a href="#">Link</a>
<div>
```

Which Ends up looking like this

> Line 1 
>   Line 2 Link

Then I tried this, which is how I would think it would be done

```
<div class="(float right class)">
    <div>Line 1<br />Line 2</div>
    <div class="(v align center class)"><a href="#">Link</div>
</div>
```

However that just stacks the link on its own line below the two text lines instead of next to it so it looks like this

> Line 1
>   Line 2
>   Link

I want it to look more like the first one just with the link vertically centered between line 1 and line 2

Comment: Why you add your class names in parenthes are you use template engine ?

Comment: Seems like very other title I tried for this post gave an error that said it already existed or wasn;t good enough.but idk what else to put besides a vertical alignment issue....so anyway hope someone can help with this because it is driving me crazy.

Comment: @Joseph no, just trying to add context to what the class does for this post

Comment: I don't believe this can be done in pure HTML. With [CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_intro.asp) on the other hand, this would be a trivial task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use flexbox for this:

```css
#container{
display:flex;
justify-content:center;
align-items:center;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
<div>
    Line 1<br />Line 2
</div>
<div>
    <a href="#">Link</a>
</div>
<div>
```